# Use a nib for duplicated views in main Storyboard

Tags: xcode, uiview, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xib

I carefully named this question because there are lots of answers but none of them quite right. I have a bunch of views in a UIStackView in my Storyboard and they are UIView subclass. They will all have the same layout, so I don't want to duplicate all of the layout work in my main Storyboard and would rather create a xib file that those views will use. I know that I can load a xib from my bundle and then extract the view from it, but that doesn't respect the constraints from the main Storyboard and also doesn't allow me to connect my outlets properly. So, my question is: is there are way to link a xib to a UIView subclass and tell my main Storyboard to use it?